# Chrome Extension message passing : verify the sender

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension in which content-script sends a message to background script.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

When background.js receives this message it get's the sender information which has

```
{ ID, tab, url }
```

I want to verify that this message was sent by content script that belong to my extension and nothing else.

How do I verify the sender ID, how can a background.js get the extension ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to.

There are two distinct events relating to messages:

1. `chrome.runtime.onMessage` - it is **only** for messages sent by your own extension. `sender` is used to determine context, i.e. tab ID.
2. `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` - it is **only** for messages sent by other sources, be it another extension or a webpage. There, `sender` will contain either an extension ID or the URL of the page in question.

   Note that you can explicitly restrict the possible senders of external messages in the manifest, in the [`externally_connectable` key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable). The default policy is to disallow web pages and allow all extensions.

Comment: so to summarize I have to add     "externally_connectable": {"ids": [], "matches":[]} In my manifest.json and make sure I only have onMessage calls in my javascript so that no one can connect?

Comment: To summarize, don't listen to `onMessageExternal` if you don't need to, and that's it. Start worrying only if you need it.